# I want to know the x and y axes labels of dbscan (sklearn) algorithm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan, clustering-key

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-dbscan-py

This is the link of sklearn dbcsan.

Comment: x and y labels has no relation with dbscan algorithm. These are just two dimensions of the dataset generated using `make_blobs` function. If want to know more about this function read [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html)